# Tracking object retain calls

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, retaincount

How do I track what is retaining my object? I have an object that isn't `delloc`-ing as expected when it is removed from a list. My suspicion is that something is incrementing the retain count, so I'd like to know how I can ideally create a place to break into the code anytime that object's retain count is incremented.

Answer (score 2):

The best possible answer is to use Instruments;  it'll track retains/releases all day long.

http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/

If desperate, override -retain to simply `return [super retain];`.   That'll give you a method you can conveniently set a breakpoint on.   You could then use breakpoint commands to do something like:

```
bt
continue
```

That'll cause the debugger to spew the backtrace of every call, when hit, and then continue.